# QGIS does not read all .csv Excel columns

Tags: qgis, excel

When I import my data from Excel into QGIS, the GPS points are found. However, not all columns that are present in the Excel are shown in the Attribute Table. At times, they have completely disappeared, other times the headers and data have moved around mixing up the headers.

When the data IS there, when I go to categorize the data, it does not show all column options, meaning I cannot categorize on the data that I actually want to categorize on.

Would anybody know what might be going on?

I have tried uploading in many different shapes and formats (at the moment 30+ times).

Comment: Hard to tell without a sample of your data, or a good look at it together with your exact workflow. How are you making the CSV file, for example? What does the CSV look like?

Comment: It works now! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something went wrong when exporting the Excel to .csv. Typically there could be a mix up between decimal seperators, especially if they are also used in a field that contains text. Have you tried using `;` instead of `,` as a comma seperator?

If your Excel is a bit more complex, or if you just want to spare the extra step to export to .CSV. You can **use the 'Spreadsheet Layers' Plugin [(link)](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/SpreadsheetLayers/)**. It's quite powerfull.

Once you have installed it, the **direct import of Excel files** can be starte here:
[image]
Make sure to check the right columns for X and Y (they are usualy detected, if the column-names are meaningfull) and make sure there's just a single table in the Excel-Sheet (check out the 'End of file detection, too).

Comment: Hey there, thank you for the reply!

I tried the plugin, it loads in the Excel, but the GPS points are no longer in the same place as where they are supposed to be (and where they are when adding as a csv file)?

I tried both with ; and , - but remain to have the same issue.

Comment: Update: it actually works now! After trying and retrying with the commas a couple of times, thank you

Comment: Hi, if you know, WHY it did work it would be nice if you write it down here, so that ohters can profit from your solution (you can even write it as your own answer). Otherwise checking the above response as 'solving your problem' also finds other people to find usefull questions and ansewrs.

Comment: Yes, of course. It worked by firstly adding the spreadsheet extension and then in addition by reorganizing the columns and rows of the excel to minimize potential errors, I also check for any emtpy cells and added NA or - to those cells. Thank you